# JavaScript/JQuery Enable backbutton behaviour for a iframe in Cordova

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, cordova, iframe

I am developing a Webview Application in Cordova. This webview App has iframe where I am showing the Content from my website. [Layout of my webview app, Black portion is the iframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PmMGD.png)

```
<body style="background-color: #f8f8f8">
<div id="web_container">
    <iframe id="main_content"
        src="https://www.mycollegepicks.in/home"
        style="margin: auto auto; overflow: hidden; border: 1px solid #f8f8f8"></iframe>
</div>
<div id='error' style='display: none'></div>
   <div id="menu_wrapper" style="min-height: 40px">
    <div>
        <img class="menu_item_img" src="img/home.png"
            style="width: 36px; padding: 2px;" id="home_btn">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="menu_item_img" src="img/arrow_left.png"
            style="width: 36px; padding: 2px;" id="back_btn">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="menu_item_img" src="img/refresh.png"
            style="width: 36px; padding: 2px;" id="reload_btn">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="menu_item_img" src="img/arrow_right.png"
            style="width: 36px; padding: 2px;" id="forward_btn">
    </div>
    <div>
        <img class="menu_item_img" src="img/shut_down.png"
            style="width: 36px; padding: 2px;" id="logout_btn">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

I have written following JS -

```
$( "#logout_btn" ).click(function() {
  showToast('Logging Out', 'info');
  console.log("Logout Button Clicked");
  logout_user();

});
$( "#reload_btn" ).click(function() {
  showToast('Reloading Page', 'info');
  console.log("Reload Button Clicked");
  $( '#main_content' ).attr( 'src', function ( i, val ) { return val; });
});

$( "#home_btn" ).click(function() {
  console.log("Home Button Clicked");
  $( '#main_content' ).attr( 'src','https://www.mycollegepicks.in/home?app=1&tab_type=home');
});

$( "#back_btn" ).click(function() {
  console.log("Back Button Clicked");
  iFrameHistory = document.getElementById("main_content").contentWindow.history.length;
  if(iFrameHistory)
    document.getElementById('main_content').contentWindow.history.back();
  writeLog("iFrameHistory "+iFrameHistory);
  PopeyeLogger('Iframe History Length '+iFrameHistory,'info');
});
$( "#forward_btn" ).click(function() {
  console.log("Forward Button Clicked");
  iFrameHistory = document.getElementById("main_content").contentWindow.history.length;
  if(iFrameHistory)
    document.getElementById('main_content').contentWindow.history.forward();
  writeLog("iFrameHistory "+iFrameHistory);
  PopeyeLogger('Iframe History Length '+iFrameHistory,'info');
});
```

But clicking on the backbutton redirects to previous page instead of iframe page back.

Note : In iframe every page load and change made via ajax. On every ajax we push the url to browser state.

Comment: Might be simular to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30973368/iframe-history-back-issues-in-cordova-app-ios

Comment: are you using Jquery mobile?

Comment: No, I'm using jquery only.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the solution that worked for me is a simple trick. Replace the :

```
   <a data-rel="back" data-icon="back">back</a>
by
    <a data-id="persistent" href="the page_before" data-transition="slide" data-icon="back"> back</a>
```

It worked fine